# Relationship between SPACE(t(n)) and DTIME(t(n))

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

I'm new to complexity theory and am analyzing inclusions between complexity classes. Suppose we are given the following seven complexity classes

1. $DTIME(n)$
2. $DTIME(n^2)$
3. $DTIME(2^n)$
4. $DTIME(2^{2^n})$
5. $SPACE(\log^2n)$
6. $SPACE(n/\log n)$
7. $SPACE(n)$

We have that

$DTIME(n)\subseteq SPACE(n) \subseteq NSPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(2^n)$

and by the Time Hierarchy Theorem,

$DTIME(n)\subseteq DTIME(n^2) \subseteq DTIME(2^n) \subseteq DTIME(2^{2^n})$

So, my gut feeling is that

$SPACE(\log^2n) \subseteq DTIME(n) \subseteq DTIME(n^2) \subseteq SPACE(n/\log n) \subseteq SPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(2^n) \subseteq DTIME(2^{2^n})$

However, I'm not sure where $SPACE(\log^2 n)$ and $SPACE(n/\log n)$ fit in. I think that this follows from the Space Hierachy Theorem -

$${SPACE}\left(o(f(n))\right) \subsetneq SPACE(f(n))$$

Is there another theorem or result I could review to justify my proposed order?

Comment: "and by the Time Hierarchy Theorem, [...]" The time hierarchy theorem only tells you those are *proper* inclusions. The inclusions themselves follow directly from the definition of the time (and space) complexities (i.e., any TM with time complexity $t$ is included in $\mathbf{TIME}(t')$ if $t < t'$).

Comment: Also, I am not sure your inclusion $\mathbf{SPACE}(n) \subseteq \mathbf{DTIME}(2^n)$ is correct. A TM using space $f(n)$ must run in time $f(n) 2^{f(n)}$, so for $f(n) = n$ we get a bound of $n 2^n$, not $2^n$. Possibly you are thinking about $\mathbf{DTIME}(2^{O(n)}) = \mathbf{E}$, which is a (much) larger class.

Comment: Why do you think $\mathsf{SPACE}(\log^2 n)$ is contained in $\mathsf{DTIME}(n)$?

Comment: I thought that $SPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(2^n)$ because $SPACE(n) \subset DTIME(2^{O(n)})$. Although, I likely interpreted this wrong as you suggested that this would mean $SPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(n2^n)$, not $SPACE(n) \subseteq DTIME(2^n)$. I think that $SPACE(log^2 n)$ is contained in $DTIME(n)$ by the same property above ($SPACE(n) \subset DTIME(2^{O(n)})$). I think I am misinterpreting what this property means.